# Rendered image looks much darker than in render preview

Tags: rendering, color

Per title, my rendered image looks much darker than in render preview

I would like to know how to fix the problem

Please see below comparison:
[image]

I'm on below setting:

- MacBook Pro 2019
- Saved in OpenEXR, Float(Full)

[image]

- color management as below
  (tried "View transform" both in filmic and standard, both look dull in rendered OpenEXR)
  [image]

-Don't think my composition is related to the color problem
[image]

-Still look dull even after importing back the OpenEXR to blender video editing

[image]

Also enclosing my blender at below link file for your reference

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YCXYqldqrIo63-DFTKgpuz0cU_XLguF2/view?usp=share_link

If anyone can troubleshoot this and help me I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

EXR format stores all raw values in precise way, because color channel information is stored as 32 bit floats as opposed to 8bit unsigned integers we see in most regular everyday image formats that we view images in. Not only that, but EXR does not apply any color transforms to those values so color management settings have absolutely no effect on the way renders are saved if you use EXR format. The color values are linear in EXR format. This is very useful, when you want to render something, but continue processing the images after the render is done because that way you can manipulate the linear color values any way you want before applying color transforms and saving it to a format more practical for content consumption so to speak.

What you are observing is different ways different applications deal with that raw linear color information that comes out of Blender's render. This is normal, since EXR format is meant for processing your renders, not for viewing them. It is possible to do color grading and various manipulation in other software than Blender and many people choose to do so if that is what their workflows require, but your default image viewer cannot do much with it. The easiest way for you to further process your rendered images would be to open them in Blender, edit and adjust them and save to some other format better suited for viewing like JPEG, WEBP or PNG. You would need to use the Compositor for that, but add your EXR file or file sequence with Image node instead of taking Render Layers node's output.

[image]

If compositing you do during the rendering is enough and you want to skip this post-processing step, you can just choose a different format to render to from the start.

Comment: Thanks so much! Didn't realise color management settings have no effect on EXR, it turns out alright after I adjust color management per the before render file in video editing!