# Render looks much darker then in render preview

Tags: lighting

This is how it looks in render preview:
[image]
And this is how the renderd image looks
[image]
I have found this [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283000/rendered-image-looks-much-darker-than-in-render-preview) but it does not solve my problem.
[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/10bvaUBwSa48Ei6XiOesCCupR6p8CtqT9?usp=sharing) is my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to deactivate the render visibility of the object called *ToS beach_mesh sky*:

[image]